# Arrow in chemical reaction

Tags: chemstyle

I want to write these equations: [image]

I used this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions*}
"(1)"  && CaCO3  &-> CaO + CO2 && "{\small Calcinação}" \\
"(2)"  && CaO + H2O &-> Ca(OH)2  && "{\small Hidratação}" \\
"(3)" && Ca(OH)2 +  CO2 &-> !((PCC)) (CaCO3) + H2O && "{\small Precipitação}"
\end{reactions*}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible put arrows?

Comment: You should make a complete example. How else are people supposed to know where the `reactions*` environment is defined? It's just a coincidence that I know it is from the `chemmacros` package...

Comment: `reactions*` put the arrows. Are you talking about the orange-dashed arrow, please tell me so I can edit the question.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I'm talking about orange-dashed arrow

Comment: fwiw (not tex related) “slacking of quicklime” is surely wrong? -- if it means what i learned in school in the 1960s(!), the word is “slaking” (from the verb “slake”).

Comment: @wasteofspace you are correct! And I know it. So, I will edit this name

Comment: @Pouya Can you help me with orange-dashed arrow ?

Comment: @user46548 *You* should help us listening to cgnieder comment: it's recommended that you provide us a *complete* and compilable example (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: @Manuel Sorry for my incomplete code. I has just edited.

Comment: @user46548, does my answer solve you problem?

Comment: No, because I dont understand tikz package. I only want the dashed arrow from CO2 to CO2. I want add this arrow to my code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `chemmacros` package so I did it in `Tikz` (this not by any mean that I know Tikz what so ever!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\mm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
            \quad 
             & \textrm{Burning of limestone}\quad      & \mm{CaCO_3}                                               & \longrightarrow & \mm{\color{cyan}CaO\color{black}+\color{orange}CO_2} & \\
             & \textrm{Slacking of quicklime}\quad     & \mm{\color{cyan}CaC\color{black} + H_2O}                  & \longrightarrow & \mm{\color{cyan}Ca(OH)_2}                            & \\
             & \textrm{\color{cyan}Percipitation}\quad & \mm{\color{cyan}Ca(OH)_2\color{black}+\color{orange}CO_2} & \longrightarrow & \mm{\color{cyan}\mathbf{CaCO_3}\color{black}+H_2O}   & \\
             &                                         &                                                           &                 & \hspace{6pt} \scriptstyle(\mm{PCC})\\};

        \draw[-stealth,color=orange,thick,densely dashed] (m-1-5.east) -| (m-3-5.south east) |- (m-3-3.south east); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]